# Disabled (by manual switch) step affects Simulink simulations. Why?

Tags: simulation, simulink, estimation

I am trying to recover some basic knowledge of nonlinear state estimations and I have chosen a box sliding on a surface, with nonlinear friction. I have however noticed that my simulations are acting weird. I wanted to test different inputs (applied force), so I have used a few steps and a constant, with a few manual switches. When the manual switches are set so that the constant input is used in the dynamics equations, the system shows some weird behavior at the step times from the *disabled* step inputs. I have tried changing the step time, the behavior follow with it (see the figures).

**Why do idle unused steps affect the simulations? They should not be used in the calculations! Does it have something to do with the step time of the solver?**

In my system, the first state (yellow in the figures) is the velocity and the second state is the position (blue in the figures). It is the velocity that reacts to the step times (State1, or derivative of State2)

[image]
*Figure 1: Highlights the effect from the input 'Step 1'. The graphs come from 'Scope' (system state) and 'Scope1' (system state derivatives). The step at time t=3s is disabled, the constant is used as input. State1 (Yellow) is the velocity, State2 (blue) is the position.*

[image]
*Figure 2: Highlights the effect from the input 'Step 1'. The graphs come from 'Scope' (system state) and 'Scope1' (system state derivatives). The step is disabled as it was in Figure 1, but the step time is increased to t=7. State1 (Yellow) is the velocity, State2 (blue) is the position.*

[image]
*Figure 3: Highlights the effect from the inputs 'Step' and 'Step1'. The graphs come from 'Scope' (system state) and 'Scope1' (system state derivatives). Both steps are disabled as inputs, with step times at t=5s respectively t=3s. Both steps gives a sudden increase in velocity at the step times.*

Comment: Very strange.  What do the simulations look like if you completely remove the steps from the model? i.e. just have the constant block with no switch or step blocks.

Comment: @Phil Sorry for the long time before an answer. If I remove the steps from the model, the effect is gone ([see the figure here](https://imgur.com/a/XFovx)). I did deactivate my MATLAB function with the manual switch in this picture. I did some modification of the function which resulted in unstable behavior (too small time steps are taken). However, the effect I have been talking about was there even if I used the constant as in the last picture. You'll have to trust me on that.
This is really weird. :/


Any ideas?

Comment: It is weird.  Can you post a minimal model showing the behavior, so that others can run it?  (I recognize that may be difficult, and is based on the contents of your MATLAB Function blocks.)

Comment: @Phil I can't seem to recreate the problem right now with a simplified model. I will try again another day, if I have the time. Thank you for your interest so far!